# Windows Phone event not firing for the second time

Tags: c#, events, windows-phone-8

I have a problem trying to fire an event for a second time. The example code below displays a login page to a user and fires an event when completed. If the user fails to login or declines they are presented with a warning and asked if they would like to try again. If they accept and login or not the second event is not firing?

I have tried:

```
    ShowLogon(new EventHandler(ourEvent);
```

also defining the warn user method as:

```
    private void warnUser(Object sender)
```

And defined an event as below but in both cases the second event when login failed does not fire the player_loginCompleted method, why?

```
    EventHandler ourEvent = new EventHandler(player_LogonCompleted);

    private void chronoButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       ShowLogon(ourEvent);   <--- shows login page and fires event
    }

    void player_LogonCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if(playerLoggedIn)
       {
            starGame();
       }
       else
       {
             warnUser();
       }
    }

    void warnUser()
    {
           // login failed or user cancelled so warn them and ask them if they would like to sign up/in
        if (MessageBox.Show("Center, Leaderboards, Achievements and announcements will not be awarded if your not logged in!",
                    "Would you like to log in now?", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel) != MessageBoxResult.OK)
        {
            // User declined to sign up
            Debug.WriteLine("Player declined to login");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Player accepted to login");
            // Show Center sign up page
            ShowLogon(ourEvent);  <--- here showing login page but not firing the event again
        }
     }
```

Many thanks

Comment: Did you try applying breakpoints? Doesn't it break into the else condition even?

Comment: There's some missing pieces here, such as the code of the `ShowLogon` method

Comment: @Kulasangar Yes it breaks into the else condition but on return the OurEven t doesn't fire?

Comment: @KooKiz I dont have the code for the ShowLogon, it's an overloaded method that accepts an EventHandler that fires upon completion. (which is what I'm attempting to do).

Comment: try adding an     `else if(<write the condition again with ==MessageBoxResult.OK)` or paste your exception with stack trace @TripVoltage